# Error while connecting the sqlplus from shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

```
REQ_OUTPUT1=`echo $XXOLA_TOP/log/Inv/xxola_inv_item_conv_int`
echo Connecting in sqlplus
sqlplus -s $1@$TWO_TASK   <<+     > $REQ_OUTPUT1
SET VERIFY OFF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;
SET LINESIZE 500;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
  exit;
```

Above is my code to connect sqlplus from shell program.
But when i am running this i am getting below error..

line 36: warning: here-document at line 29 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `+')

Comment: What's the idea for this script - Can you explain step by step what you're trying to achieve with it; e.g. Run this as point 1, then run that as point 2. The expected result is: .... and the actual result is: !.... for instance. Thanks in advance m8 !

Comment: The error message is very clear. If you would add the line numbers it would be yot more clear. Do you know what a here-document is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not ending the here document properly. Don't use symbols like + for here document delimiters. Use proper meaningful strings.

```
REQ_OUTPUT1=`echo $XXOLA_TOP/log/Inv/xxola_inv_item_conv_int`
echo Connecting in sqlplus
sqlplus -s $1@$TWO_TASK   <<INP     > $REQ_OUTPUT1
SET VERIFY OFF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK;
SET LINESIZE 500;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
  exit;
INP
```

Comment: why not use symbols like '+' ? The '+' is not the problem. The missing '+' is the problem.

Comment: @miracle173 : I understand that + is not the problem. But,I believe a string like INP , END etc are  meaningful and increases readability.